# Application running in Windows Vista context by default

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, windows-8, operating-system

I am testing my desktop application on a Windows 8 machine and I noticed there is a new column in the Task Manager details view called "Operating system context". This shows my application running under the "Windows Vista" context.

I haven't specified anything in the application manifest to force the application to run under this context in Visual Studio. The application is a Visual C++ App and was built in Visual Studio 2010.

Don't get me wrong, the application runs smoothly on Windows 8 so I am not looking to solve crashes or bugs. It just annoys me to see such a thing and would like to fix it.

So my question is how can I make my application run under the "Windows 8" context under Windows 8?

Comment: Don't quote me, but my investigations show that only Windows Store Apps show up in the Windows 8 context. I've no idea why some are Windows 7 or Windows Vista though ;-)

Comment: @roger_rowland well most of them does, and as you said some run as Vista and some Run as 7. Chrome, when run in desktop mode, runs under Windows 8 context. So I just want to know how this is specified, does it have something to do with the executable signature? or is it a build option

Comment: I honestly don't know, but I'm now intrigued to find out! If I discover anything I'll post back so keep this question alive if possible.

Comment: not sure how I'm supposed to keep it alive, but will try :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I think [I've found the answer here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371711%28VS.85%29.aspx). It says:

> Applications without a Compatibility section in their manifest will receive Windows Vista behavior by default on Windows 7 and future Windows versions

So if you don't have *anything* in your manifest, Vista is what you get. Reading the rest of the article, it seems the best you can do is get Windows 7 rather than Windows 8, so maybe that's something specific to Store Apps?

**EDIT**

Ok, I finally found the entry you need for Windows 8:

```
<supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
```

So try putting that in the compatibility section of your manifest.

I know you're using VS2010, so this may be different, but with VS2012, I did the following:

1. Created a new WPF application
2. Right-click on project in Solution Explorer and choose Add New Item
3. Select Application manifest from the list

A new manifest is added to the project with compatibility settings commented out. A cut-down example with everything uncommented is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
  <application>
    <!-- A list of all Windows versions that this application is designed to work with. 
    Windows will automatically select the most compatible environment.-->

    <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows Vista, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
    <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"></supportedOS>

    <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 7, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
    <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>

    <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 8, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
    <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"></supportedOS>

  </application>
</compatibility>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

After rebuilding, the application shows as expected in Task Manager:

[image]

Comment: will check it and get back to you